# Wordpress -> nesteed post loop does not return the number of posts specified in 'posts_per_page' parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, nested-loops

Why the nested post loop for post_type => 'personalne' does not return the nuber of posts specified in 'posts_per_page' parameter' ?

Nested loop seems to work ok ('posts_per_page') for 2 first post_types i.e. 'konsorcjum' and 'grupy' but somehow if I specify for instance 3 as 'posts_per_page' for 'personalne' it does not return 3 posts -> it returns 0 posts i.e. nothing.

This is the link to the code: https://wtools.io/paste-code/b1Gi

This is the PHP code:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'konsorcjum',
    'where' => 't.post_status="Publish"',
    'orderby' => 'position', 
    'order' => 'ASC',  
    'posts_per_page' => 100                          
];
 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 
// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();                    
                    
  
 
                $params = array(
                'post_type' => 'grupy',
                'where' => 't.post_status="Publish"',
                'orderby' => 'position', 
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page' => 2                            
                );
 
                $group_query = new WP_Query( $params );
                // The Loop
                while ( $group_query->have_posts() ) :
                    $group_query->the_post();
 
                $nazwa_grupy = get_the_title();
 
                
 
                // NAZWA GRUPY: 
                echo get_field( "nazwa_grupy");
 
 
 
        
                                $params666 = array(
                                'post_type' => 'personalne',
                                'where' => 't.post_status="Publish"',
                                'orderby' => 'position', 
                                'order' => 'ASC',
                                'posts_per_page' => 1 
                                );
 
                                $person_query = new WP_Query( $params666 );
                                // The Loop
                                while ( $person_query->have_posts() ) :
                                    $person_query->the_post();
 
 
                                  if( have_rows('dane_osoby') ):
 
                                  while( have_rows('dane_osoby') ): the_row(); 
 
                                    echo the_sub_field( "imie_i_nazwisko", $person_query->post->ID);
 
                                
                                   endwhile;
                                   endif;  
 
 
 
                            // Koniec pętli while dla PERSONALNE:
                                endwhile;   wp_reset_postdata();
 
 
 
 
 
 
                // Koniec pętli while dla GRUPY:
                    endwhile;   wp_reset_postdata();
 
 
 
// Koniec pętli while dla KONSORCJUM:
 
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and let me know if its works.

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'konsorcjum',
    'where' => 't.post_status="Publish"',
    'orderby' => 'position', 
    'order' => 'ASC',  
    'posts_per_page' => 100                          
];
 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 
// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();                    
                    
  
 
                $params = array(
                'post_type' => 'grupy',
                'where' => 't.post_status="Publish"',
                'orderby' => 'position', 
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page' => 2                            
                );
 
                $group_query = new WP_Query( $params );
                // The Loop
                while ( $group_query->have_posts() ) :
                    $group_query->the_post();
 
                $nazwa_grupy = get_the_title();
 
                
 
                // NAZWA GRUPY: 
                echo get_field( "nazwa_grupy");
 
 
 
        
                                $params666 = array(
                                'post_type' => 'personalne',
                                'where' => 't.post_status="Publish"',
                                'orderby' => 'position', 
                                'order' => 'ASC',
                                'posts_per_page' => 1 
                                );
 
                                $person_query = new WP_Query( $params666 );
                                // The Loop
                                while ( $person_query->have_posts() ) :
                                    $person_query->the_post();
 
 
                                  if( have_rows('dane_osoby') ):
 
                                  while( have_rows('dane_osoby') ): the_row(); 
 
                                    echo the_sub_field( "imie_i_nazwisko", $person_query->post->ID);
 
                                
                                   endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
                                   endif;  
 
 
 
                            // Koniec pętli while dla PERSONALNE:
                                endwhile;   wp_reset_postdata();
 
 
 
 
 
 
                // Koniec pętli while dla GRUPY:
                    endwhile;   wp_reset_postdata();
 
 
 
// Koniec pętli while dla KONSORCJUM:
 
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: No, 'while( have_rows('dane_osoby') ): the_row();' is not the issue because later in the same php file I am using 'while( have_rows('dane_osoby') ): the_row();' from the same 'personalne' post type as the second step in the nested loop -> and it works correctly

Comment: maulik zwt -> I tried your solution it does not work

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I write inside 'post_type' => 'personalne' - 'posts_per_page' => 100, it returns all records

Comment: It's strange, if it is then removed where clause and try with posts_per_page 1 and tried .. if its help.